# Data doesn't get pulled into front end - react

Tags: reactjs

I've a JSON as shown:

```
{
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0,
   "cnt":40,
   "list":[
      {
         "dt":1601024400,
         "main":{
            "temp":301.11,
            "feels_like":301.34,
            "temp_min":301.11,
            "temp_max":301.2,
            "pressure":1010,
            "sea_level":1010,
            "grnd_level":907,
            "humidity":58,
            "temp_kf":-0.09
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":68
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":4.24,
            "deg":238
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0.25,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2020-09-25 09:00:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've written a `React` code to pull the data.
Code:

```
import React from 'react';
// async
import { useAsync } from 'react-async';

const loadUsers = async () =>
  await fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid={API_KEY}")
    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(res => res.json())
  

export default function Dashboard() {
   
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync(
        { 
            promiseFn: loadUsers 
        }
    )
    if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
    if (error) return `Something went wrong: ${error.message}`
    console.log("Data is", data)
    if (data)

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Weather Details</h2>
            </div>
            {data.list.map((weather, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="row"> 
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <p>{weather.temp_min}</p>
                    <p>{weather.temp_max}</p>
                </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

But it is empty as shown here...
[image: Dashboard]
How can I pull the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your data is actually being pulled into the frontend, but if it is, I think the issue is when you map over it.  When you use `data.list.map((weather, index) => (`, in that instance `weather` is each item in `list`.  So instead of `weather.min_temp` (which doesn't exist) I think you're looking for `weather.main.min_temp` and `weather.main.max_temp`.

```
{data.list.map((weather, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="row"> 
    <div className="col-md-12">
        <p>{weather.main.temp_min}</p>
        <p>{weather.main.temp_max}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
))}
```

As an aside, it's not recommended to use index as a `key`.  Maybe the `dt` is a unique value that you can use as a key?

Comment: Oh okay... Thank you, I was referring to this for `key` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/4185813